# C function definition/prototype

Tags: c

I'm new to learning the C programming language and this question is confusing for me because I thought the compiler will have an error.

Assuming a function is called before its definition/prototype occurs, which one of the following is false concerning its arguments?

A. All char types are converted to type int.

B. All short types are converted to type int.

C. All float types are converted to type double.

D. All types other than char, short, and float are passed unaltered.

E. Each argument is converted to the type of its corresponding formal parameter.

Comment: This seems like a textbook (no pun intended) case of homework answer requests.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  This question is not currently very appropriate for SO — the answer's E, but you have to write more than that in the answer.  The real issue is "How would you learn from us telling you that E is the answer".  What do you understand about what function prototypes do?  Also, C99 and C11 both require functions to be declared before they're used.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is why you have 250k. Thank you for contributing to questions like these (in the thoroughness and class that you do). And, congrats on the upcoming 250k milestone.

Comment: In my notes it says that constraints for C are stated in X3.159-1989 and I looked at the wiki article here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C so it seems like the standard is C89/C90.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a function call in C89 or C90 (same thing; one is ANSI C, t'other is ISO C), then:

- The return type is assumed to be `int`.
- Type `char` (and `signed char` and `unsigned char`) and `short` (and `unsigned short`) are converted to `int` (or, exceptionally, `unsigned int` if it was `unsigned short` and `sizeof(unsigned short) == sizeof(unsigned int)`), and `float` is converted to `double`.
- Note that pointers are not changed.
- The function is assumed not to be a varargs function.  You must have a prototype in scope to call a varargs function such as `printf()` or `scanf()` correctly.

So, the answer is E.

The standard (current version, ISO/IEC 9899:2011) says:

> #### 6.5.2.2 Function calls
>
> ¶6 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a
>   prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that
>   have type `float` are promoted to double. These are called the default argument
>   promotions. If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the
>   behavior is undefined. If the function is defined with a type that includes a prototype, and
>   either the prototype ends with an ellipsis (`, ...`) or the types of the arguments after
>   promotion are not compatible with the types of the parameters, the behavior is undefined.
>   If the function is defined with a type that does not include a prototype, and the types of
>   the arguments after promotion are not compatible with those of the parameters after
>   promotion, the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases:
>
> - one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the
>     corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;
> - both types are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of a character type or
>     `void`.

Note that getting it 'wrong' leads to *undefined behaviour*, and undefined behaviour should be avoided at all costs.  The program could do anything — including erasing all the files on your computer — and that is acceptable according to the standard.  Actually, programs seldom do that (and even more seldom cause 'demons to fly out of your nose', leading to the phrase 'nasal demons' (search for it), but that would also be acceptable in the face of undefined behaviour).

You should make it a policy that you never call a function without a prototype in scope if at all possible.  All new code should meet that criterion; if you are unlucky enough to have to maintain ancient code that doesn't, you may have to go with the flow, but aim to get to the point where all your code can be compiled with options such as `-Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Werror` in effect.  Those are GCC options that report on problems with function prototypes and function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

See what happens when a function call is made if

***1. Compiler has encountered a prototype prior to yhe call:***

The value of each argument converted implicitly to the type of the corresponding parameters as if by assignment.

***2. The compiler has not encountered a prototype prior to the call:***

The compiler will perform *default argument promotions*: (1) `float` arguments are converted to `double`. (2) the integral promotions are performed, causing `char` and `short` arguments to be converted to `int` (In C99, integer promotions are performed).
So the answer is

> E. Each argument is converted to the type of its corresponding formal parameter.

But keep in mind that **relying on default promotions is dangerous**. Consider this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
     double x = 3.0;
     printf("Square: %d\n", square(x));

     return 0;
}

int square(int n)
{
     return n*n;
}
```

At the time `square` is called, the compiler hasn't seen a prototype yet, so it doesn't know that square expects an argument of type `int`. Instead, the compiler performs the default argument promotions on `x`, with no effect. Since it expecting an argument of type `int` but has been given a `double` value instead, the effect of calling `square` is **undefined**.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!
I found the answer.

+All subintegers (char and short) are converted to type int or unsigned.

+All type float are converted to type double.

+All other types are unaltered.

So yeah the answer is E.

Thanks for the moral support!

Comment: You need to be aware that as of the 1999 standard, you are not permitted to call a function without a visible declaration; the above applies only when there is a visible declaration, but it's not a prototype. This is important to know, but in practice you should *always* have a visible prototype for any function you call (usually obtained by `#include`ing the appropriate header). Old-style non-prototype function declarations are obsolescent and rarely useful; prototypes are just better. (A "prototype" is a function declaration that specifies the types of any parameters.)